# Multiple search query in vbs /.bat

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript

```
@echo off
call :inputbox "Enter the imput" "JIFFY"
echo You entered %Input% too late to back down now :)
start "search1" "www.google.com"
start "search2" "www.duckduckgo.com"
start "search3" "www.wolframalpha.com"
exit /b
:InputBox
set input=
set heading=%~2
set message=%~1
echo wscript.echo inputbox(WScript.Arguments(1),WScript.Arguments(0)) >"%temp%\input.vbs"
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('cscript //nologo "%temp%\input.vbs" "%message%" "%heading%"') do set input=%%a
exit /b
```

I don't understand what lines 10 to 13 do exacty. The idea is to gather and process up to 3 inputs to run search queries in search engines using the start command. I manage to do it with 1, but am not sure how to do multiple prompting only 1 input box. Also, am not sure what the temp file created is doing and the `set heading=%~2` and `set message=%~1` variables' function.

Answer (score 0):

To understand what the lines 10 and 11 are doing you first need to understand what the lines 2 and 8 are doing:

```
@echo off
call :inputbox "Enter the imput" "JIFFY"
...
:InputBox
...
```

The batch [`call`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490873.aspx) statement can not only run other other batch scripts, but also can re-run the current batch script starting from the given label (here `:InputBox`). Basically, you're re-running the script, but executing only its second half:

```
set input=
set heading=%~2
set message=%~1
echo wscript.echo inputbox(WScript.Arguments(1),WScript.Arguments(0)) >"%temp%\input.vbs"
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('cscript //nologo "%temp%\input.vbs" "%message%" "%heading%"') do set input=%%a
exit /b
```

The lines 10 and 11 assign the arguments of the `call` statement to the variables `heading` and `message`.

Line 12 then creates a temporary VBScript file that displays an [`InputBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3yfdhzk5) and echoes whatever the user entered into that input box.

Finally, line 13 runs the VBScript, passing `%heading%` and `%message%` as the title and text of the input box. Because the script is run with the commandline interpreter `cscript.exe` the echoed output is written to STDOUT, and assigned to the variable `input` by the [`for`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx) loop. That variable remains populated after the `call` returns, so you can output `%input%` in line 3 (and potentially use it in your searches).

To actually search for the input you'd need to call the search engine URLs with the correct parameters, though. For instance, you'd launch a Google search like this:

```
start "title" "http://www.google.com/search?q=%input%"
```

Other search engines probably have different parameters, so you need to check that for each engine. Also, you may need to handle special characters and multiple search terms in `input` (e.g. `foo bar baz` → `foo+bar+baz`).

Comment: Indeed, thank you, I am looking to run this %input% on several manipulated URL's , but some of them have 2 and 3 form input boxes, I have to constanly run multiple searches on several search engines every day at the job.

Comment: The number of input fields on the web page isn't that relevant. What matters is whether you can construct a single URL to execute the query.

Comment: This an example of 1 of them: [https://box.tool.com/tools/v3/?ts=tool&item_id=%Input%&=fname&fn_item=&customer_id="data_query"client&item="data_query"&location_id=1] , I was able to manipulate this and a few others.  its strange that after the query , the strings double in size, its easy to spot where the query's are.